# Kendo().ComboBox() in a template - how to set SelectedIndex

Tags: telerik, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-combobox

Have a grid-template with a kendo combobox in:

```
 <script id="templateSample" type="text/kendo-tmpl">

    @*Active holds the selected value*@
    # alert(Active) # //

    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("ComboBoxSample")
        .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "true",
                Text = "Yes",
                Selected = false,
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "false",
                Text = "No",
                Selected = false,
            }
        })
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .SelectedIndex(1)
        .ToClientTemplate()
    )
  </script>
```

The template appears whenever a row is expanded (see http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy).

I can't figure out how to set selected index with the item currently selected.

To set selected item, I can chose to use SelectListItem.Selected or Combobox.SelectedItem, but how to set a value from the item currently showing in the template ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this problem using javascript.

Add an event to the grid:

```
.Events(e=>e.DetailInit("aftertemplateload"))
```

And the script:

```
    function aftertemplateload(e) {
        $("#ComboBoxSample" + e.data.Id).data("kendoComboBox").value(e.data.Active);
    }
```

and remember to add the new id to the combobox:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("ComboBoxSample#=Id#")
        .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
        { etc...
```